# Converting animated button style from css to styled-componenet

Tags: html, css, reactjs, styled-components

While browsing net looking for a button style to apply to my register form's button, i found this nice animated button code, but it's in a simple `HTML` & `CSS`. i tried to convert theses to `styled-component` but i can't manage to make it 100% the same as it looks in [codepen](https://codepen.io/thelaazyguy/pen/brryVq). Can you correct my code to make it similar to the original ones?

HTML :

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="#"><span>Hover Me!</span></a>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.wrapper{
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

a{
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  transition: all .35s;
}

a span{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

a:after{
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ff003b;
  transition: all .35s;
}

a:hover{
  color: #fff;
}

a:hover:after{
  width: 100%;
}
```

My try JSX :

```
const Button = styled.button`
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
  border: 2px solid teal;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.35s;
`;
const Span = styled.span`
  &:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "CREATE";
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background: teal;
    transition: all 0.35s;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  &:hover {
    color: white;
  }
  &:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
  }
`;

const Register = () => {
  return (
    <div>
        <Button>
            <Span>CREATE</Span>
        </Button>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Register;
```

Answer (score 0):

you put the `&:after`, `&:hover` and `&:hover:after` on the `span` and not on the `button` element.

try:

```
const Button = styled.button`
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
  border: 2px solid teal;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.35s;
  &:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "CREATE";
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background: teal;
    transition: all 0.35s;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  &:hover {
    color: white;
  }
  &:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
  }
`;
const Span = styled.span`
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
`;
```